# If unity gets a plugin framework/API of some sort, what languages will be available?

Tags: unity

With unity being ported to compiz (I read somewhere as a plugin?), will unity be getting a plugin/extension framework of some sort? ***If yes***, what languages are on the table? Python, Vala, C++? Or will it be something more like GObject-Introspection?

Along with this, are widgets/gadgets/miniapps/w.e planned?

*Please let me know if to split the question.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[In addition to what Murat said](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10820/if-unity-gets-a-plugin-framework-api-of-some-sort-what-languages-will-be-availab/10822#10822), the pluggable renderers may make it possible for items to paint themselves, creating the possibility a widgets place. The unity team has no plans for an official widgets layer or anything like that, but the possibility may exist when pluggable renderers are implemented. However; since none of this is actually coded, it remains to be seen what will actually be doable via renderers.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the existing [Places architecture](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/Places), and the "[Unity Architecture](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=Unity_Architecture.pdf)" document. You'll note that Places renderers are going to be pluggable, and that there's a DBus API for daemons that are meant to expose Places entries, which translates to the whole thing being largely language-independent.

There's a [sample place](https://launchpad.net/unity-place-sample), and a [YouTube place branch](https://code.launchpad.net/~njpatel/unity-place-sample/unity-place-youtube) in the same project that you may want to study.

Widgets and the like can be implemented as or in places, as well as Compiz plugins as before. You can expect there to be design guidelines advising developers on the scope of Places (similar to [the ones for application indicators](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/CustomStatusMenuDesignGuidelines)) soon.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the other good answers, the libraries created by the DX team tend to be written in Vala which means that any language with GObject-introspection bindings will be supported.  Currently Python (and obviously Vala) are the only non-C languages with GObject-introspection bindings that I'm aware of, but I'd expect more languages to pick up bindings in the future (I know there's at least one set of Mono gis bindings in the pipeline).

That's in as well as the DBus interfaces which are language-agnostic.

Comment: I think the DBUS architecture is what I'm really stoked about =)... time do some reading